# Regex: Match from second occurence

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I`d created a regex for matching nth occurence in the string:

```
^(?:[^-]*-){2}([^-].*)
```

However, testing it in the [regex tool](https://www.regex101.com/r/tX6xL0/1) did not get 100% matching solution:

For example:

origin: ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath - 151 Grams

expected: ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath

tested: ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre

origin: AST Sports Science - R-ALA 200 - 90 Capsules

expected:  AST Sports Science - R-ALA 200

tested: AST Sports Science - R

I understand that in given above regex it is matches second occurrence of "-", and I`d created next regex:

```
^(?:[^-]*\s-\s){2}([^-].*)
```

But it is misses the examples above at all.

What I miss for the perfect regex work?

Thanks for help.

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/29 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
>>> s = 'ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath - 151 Grams'
>>> s1 = 'AST Sports Science - R-ALA 200 - 90 Capsules'
>>> re.search(r'^(?:.*? - .*?)(?= - )', s).group()
'ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath'
>>> re.search(r'^(?:.*? - .*?)(?= - )', s1).group()
'AST Sports Science - R-ALA 200'
```

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/29

You could use `re.sub` function also.

```
>>> re.sub(r' - (?:(?! - ).)*$', '', s)
'ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath'
>>> re.sub(r' - (?:(?! - ).)*$', '', s1)
'AST Sports Science - R-ALA 200'
```

This matches the last part of `<space>hyphen<space>` delimited string. Replacing the match with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Comment: My regex algorithm works with re.sub(), how to change you regex in order to work with this function??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for this regex: `(?m)^(.*)(\s+\-\s+(?!\s\-\s).*)$`

Sample code in Python:

```
str1 = 'ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath - 151 Grams'
str2 = 'Anjolie Ayurveda - Rosemary Lavender and Neem Tulsi Soap Herbal Gift Box - CLEARANCE PRICED Nourish Your Skin & Awaken Your Senses'
print re.sub(r"(?m)^(.*)(\s+\-\s+(?!\s\-\s).*)$", "\g<1>", str1)
print re.sub(r"(?m)^(.*)(\s+\-\s+(?!\s\-\s).*)$", "\g<1>", str2)
```

Output:

```
ANIMAL - Animal Rage XL Pre-Workout Grape of Wrath                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Anjolie Ayurveda - Rosemary Lavender and Neem Tulsi Soap Herbal Gift Box
```

Comment: Thanks man , I combine mine and your regexes with a little bit changes. You can check here https://www.regex101.com/r/tX6xL0/2

Comment: Sorry, I did not have Internet connection for a long time. Doesn't `^(.*)(?=\s+\-\s+\d)` serve you better? https://www.regex101.com/r/tX6xL0/3.

Comment: I have to work with re.sub(). You regex works with re.search().group

Comment: I see, I updated the answer. Anyway, if you are happy with Avinash Raj's solution, it is OK.

Comment: Thanks you solution is better but it is it is not always digit also a word can be come after "-":
Anjolie Ayurveda - Rosemary Lavender and Neem Tulsi Soap Herbal Gift Box - CLEARANCE PRICED Nourish Your Skin & Awaken Your Senses
I fixed this with specifying words but if you have any idea about regex fix will be owe you.

Comment: I think Avinash's approach is the correct one: use the negative lookahead to make sure we are capturing the part of string after the last " - " occurrence. You do not owe me anyting :)